# Secant method using python

Tags: python, math

How would you write python code to find the root of the non linear equation fnon(x) = 0 using the secant method? Using secant(fnon,x0,x1,tol) returning x as the computed root and f as the function value at that root. My method isn't working

Comment: Did you try a simple example "by hand"? On which step does the code produce a different result? Could you see why? Did you then try slightly more complicated examples? Did you write out the steps in full, either via `print` or via a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

A solution provided by [the website "Solving nonlinear algebraic equations"](http://hplgit.github.io/prog4comp/doc/pub/p4c-sphinx-Python/._pylight007.html) which has additional ways to calculate it.

```
def secant(f, x0, x1, eps):
        f_x0 = f(x0)
        f_x1 = f(x1)
        iteration_counter = 0
        while abs(f_x1) > eps and iteration_counter < 100:
            try:
                denominator = float(f_x1 - f_x0)/(x1 - x0)
                x = x1 - float(f_x1)/denominator
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                print "Error! - denominator zero for x = ", x
                sys.exit(1)     # Abort with error
            x0 = x1
            x1 = x
            f_x0 = f_x1
            f_x1 = f(x1)
            iteration_counter += 1
        # Here, either a solution is found, or too many iterations
        if abs(f_x1) > eps:
            iteration_counter = -1
        return x, iteration_counter
    
    def f(x):
        return x**2 - 9
    
    x0 = 1000;   x1 = x0 - 1
    
    solution, no_iterations = secant(f, x0, x1, eps=1.0e-6)
    
    if no_iterations > 0:    # Solution found
        print "Number of function calls: %d" % (2 + no_iterations)
        print "A solution is: %f" % (solution)
    else:
        print "Solution not found!"
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
#example function
import numpy as np
fnon= lambda x: np.sin(x-np.pi)

from scipy.optimize import root_scalar
x0=0
x1=5
tol=1e-8
x= root_scalar(fnon,method='secant',x0=x0,x1=x1,rtol=tol)
print(x)
```